# SWF file loads a new url, how to grab it using Python?

Tags: python, actionscript-3, flash

I'll start with saying I'm not very familiar with AS3 coding at all, which I'm pretty sure SWF files are coded with (someone can correct me if I'm wrong)

I have a SWF file which accepts an ID parameter, within the code it takes the ID and performs some hash routines on it, eventually produces a new 'token' and within the code loads a new url using this token

I found this by taking the swf file to showmycode and decompiling

My code is in Python and the SWF file is online, I could download and save it locally

Is it possible to somehow execute the swf in python or by using urllib to grab this new url?

It doesn't seem to act the same as a redirect url, as when I do:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.geturl()
```

Just returns the url that I am requesting, so I'm not sure how or even if I can grab what is being spit out

Edit - This is the MD5 that is being used - https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5.as?r=51

Trying to find a Python equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was making things too complicated

I was able to just use python hashlib.md5 to produce the same results as the AS3 code

```
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update('test')
m.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the swf in Python? As far as I understand, you want to have the same token transformation functionality developed in Python, right?

If so - you just need to read the code and translate it into your own app. You cannot run swf from python, nor you will get any response (or "spit out" as you call it). Flash is an executable file ran from a plugin (virtual machine). You won't be able to grab anything from it nor you will be able to execute it by your own.

Comment: Thanks.. unfortunatly the code is a bit crazy, it's the MD5 hash routine from adobe (i believe), possibly is using external libs in the process though I'm not sure as I haven't tried going thru it all yet..

Comment: Well, that's how it goes when you try to get the tokenizer process :) No easy way unfortunately.

Comment: I'm hoping someone will jump in with a link to it already converted or an online routine :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is it here actually - https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5.as?r=51

Comment: That's the MD5 implementation for AS3. If you are sure that's the only thing that's done inside flash - look for a Python equivalent, 100% there is one!

Comment: Andrew thanks! That gave me the hint and led me to the right path, just using python's hashlib.md5 gave me the same results! I'll add my answer